Creating and linking thread getting error "std::Invoke, No matching overloaded function found"
        // The function that the background thread will run
        void runPingThread(std::promise<int>& promiseObj) {
            while (!stopFlag) {
                ping();  // Call the ping function
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));  // Poll every 5 seconds
                int result = 42;
                // Set the value in the promise object
                promiseObj.set_value(result);
            }
        }

        // Initialize the service and start the ping thread
        void init() {
            // Step 1: Create a promise object
            std::promise<int> promiseObj;

            // Step 2: Get a future object associated with the promise
            std::future<int> futureObj = promiseObj.get_future();

            // Step 3: Create a thread and pass the promise object
            pingThread = std::thread(&ConnectionService::runPingThread, std::ref(promiseObj));

            // Step 4: Wait for the result from the thread using future
            std::cout << "Waiting for result from thread..." << std::endl;
            int result = futureObj.get(); // Blocks until the value is set in the promise

            // Step 5: Print the result
            std::cout << "Result from thread: " << result << std::endl;

            /*
            // Start the pinging thread
            pingThread = std::thread(&ConnectionService::runPingThread, this);
            std::cout << "Ping service started..." << std::endl;*/
        }

I am getting error
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\thread(60,14): error C2672: 'invoke': no matching overloaded function found
Both functions are inside class ConnectionService

Is ConnectionService::runPingThread a static member function? If it's not, then the first "argument" to the function should be a pointer to the object you want to call it on.

Its not static, so should I used *ConnectionService::runPingThread instead of &ConnectionService::runPingThread

If I wont use argument in runPingThread then its working
pingThread = std::thread(&ConnectionService::runPingThread, this);

std::thread(&ConnectionService::runPingThread, this, std::ref(promiseObj)) And don't forget to join the thread. Which kind of makes the use of a thread not make much sense. If you need the thread to keep on running after init is called, you need to pass the promise by value instead. Or perhaps use std::async instead?
